# Show contact person per country & city

Tags: php, mysql, countries

I'm working on a website with different contact persons in different countries & cities.

What I would like to achieve is when a visitor visits a page with info about France - Paris, the script will search for the contact person in the database and show the info on the page.

Problem is that a contact person can have multiple countries/cities under his responsibility.

I already have a countries and cities table. I don't want to change or add anything to these tables.

So the only thing I can think of is:

> contact_persons (table)
>
> contact_persons_id
>
> contact_persons_name

And other info...

> contact (table)
>
> contact_persons_id
>
> country
>
> city

So for example:

moonwalker - France - Paris

moonwalker - France - Marseille

otheruser - Netherlands - Utrecht

But is this ok? Or is there some other way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

p.s.: Languages are PHP and MySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalize your data in a way like described below. You have Contacts, Cities, and Countries as separate areas of data to avoid repetition. Then you have a table to map contacts to cities in a one-to-many relationship (one contact = many cities).

```
[table_contacts]
  - id
  - name

[table_cities]
  - id
  - name
  - country_id

[table_countries]
  - id
  - name

[table_contacts_cities]
  - id
  - contact_id
  - city_id
```

**[EDIT]** Simplified thanks to comment below.

Comment: I think you've gone a little over-board here. A city is, almost by definition, only in one country, though with a few exceptions that are mainly in one country. There should be no need to have a many to many relationship.

Comment: +1 but agreeing with Ben's comment that the many-to-many with cities and countries is not necessary.